# Can embedded Linux meet a 200ms timing requirement?

Tags: linux, real-time, communication

I'm working on an embedded Linux project where we need to ACK a message from the serial port within 200ms.  If I'm not using some real-time variant then won't it be impossible to guarantee Linux would respond within that time bound?  The hardware will be a 200MHz ARM running Debian.  The kernel version currently used is "2.6.32 #1 SMP PREEMPT".  Would also like to know exactly what PREEMPT means here.

Answer (score 2):

Preemptive means an arbritary task with the right priority can interrupt any task running in the scheduler of the OS at any time. With this feature you could guarantee that your task with the timing constraint can meet it's requirement.

The picture below illustrates exactly what scheduling is doing:
[image: example of preemptive scheduling]

Nowadays, virtually every popular OS support preemptive scheduling in user space. However, in kernel space (drivers, other critical kernel tasks) are not supported by this kind of scheduling so there are some initiatives like RTLinux and also your OS, [Debian SMP PREEMPT](http://www.pengutronix.de/software/linux-rt/debian_en.html) which try to support full preemptive scheduling in the OS (making it a [hard realtime system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_realtime#Hard.2C_firm.2C_and_soft_real-time)).

So yes, your kernel would provide the timing constraints needed for your application.

Comment: Good explanations.  What do I have to do in my user space app. that talks to the serial port to make it higher priority than the other processes?  It's the only process on the system that has strict timing requirements.  Also what happens in the future if someone adds another process at this high priority? (wouldn't want my process to become starved).

Comment: In linux, you can adjust the priority of the user space process with the `nice` command. See: http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice. If another process also gets the priority which is the same, it will compete with the other high priority process. You can't really say if the processes are getting equal processing time. It depends on I/O, synchronizing mechanisms and other atomic tasks.

Answer (score 1):

It means that it's a real-time kernel. Preempt means to interrupt or stop an action. So if an irq request comes into the kernel, the kernel immediately stops what it's doing and processes irq. So you get a real time response to events happening on the serial bus or an audio input.

I use build real-time kernels when needed (usually audio applications) and it's a series of patches that can be added to the vanilla kernel to make it preemptive (real time).

I don't know without testing if you can respond to a serial request in 200ms but that definitely sounds possible.

Along with Debian, RedHat and other distros with preemptive kernels, there are whole distros dedicated to realtime Linux like RTLinux and I would guess most of them would have ARM versions.